# How to create links in xterm.js

Tags: javascript, xtermjs

I am using xterm.js to write a reporting tool that displays results on the `xterm.js` Terminal. I want some of these test results that are written to the terminal to be links that when pressed I can trigger some sort of JavaScript function to handle my next step. I was looking over the documentation and found an interface called `ILink` that supposedly does what I'm looking for but I have no idea how to use it. Is xterm.js capable of something like this?

Comment: Yes, you can use the linkifier interface for that, given the parts can be identified correctly by some regexp. You might want to have a look at the code of the weblinks addon. Note that there is also a hyperlink sequence for terminals, but we dont support it yet.

Answer (score 3):

OSC 8 hyperlinks are supported since [xterm.js#4005](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/pull/4005)

based on [readme.md#addons](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js#addons)

using [xterm-addon-web-links](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/tree/master/addons/xterm-addon-web-links)

```js
import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
import { WebLinksAddon } from 'xterm-addon-web-links';

const terminal = new Terminal();
term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));

// clickable links
// default handler: open the link
terminal.loadAddon(new WebLinksAddon());
// custom handler
/*
function onLinkClick(_event, url) {
  console.log(`clicked link: ${url}`);
}
terminal.loadAddon(new WebLinksAddon(onLinkClick));
*/

// simple link
terminal.writeln('click here: https://xtermjs.org/');

// OSC 8 hyperlink escape codes
// not working in xterm.js?
terminal.writeln('click here: \x1b]8;;https://xtermjs.org\x07OSC 8 hyperlink text\x1b]8;;\x07');
```

alternative: [xterm-link-provider](https://github.com/LabhanshAgrawal/xterm-link-provider)

```js
import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
import { LinkProvider } from 'xterm-link-provider';

const terminal = new Terminal();
term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));

const linkRegex = /(CLICKME)/gu
terminal.registerLinkProvider(
  new LinkProvider(
    terminal,
    linkRegex,
    (_event, text) => {
      console.log(text)
    }
  )
)

terminal.writeln('click here: CLICKME');
```