# How does VS Code recognize URLs in text (strings)?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, url

I find that VS Code does really good URL recognition / extraction- better than any methods found in the internet. Since VS Code is opensource, where can I find the code? Probably regex rules.

[image: shortcut for nice url extraction result]

I searched the source code with keyword `url` or `extract`, but can not find any clues.

Comment: search the source code for `http` or `https`, these strings should be part of the regex used, maybe `https?://`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For the builtin link detection in editors

Not 100% percent sure that this is it, but from my search through the source code, I think you might be looking for [`src/vs/editor/common/languages/linkComputer.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/common/languages/linkComputer.ts), which uses a state-machine-based approach.

You can see in [`src/vs/editor/browser/services/editorWorkerService.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/browser/services/editorWorkerService.ts), in `EditorWorkerService`'s constructor, there's a comment saying "`register default link-provider and default completions-provider`", and a call to `client.computeLinks`, which is defined in [`src/vs/editor/common/services/editorSimpleWorker.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/common/services/editorSimpleWorker.ts) in the `EditorSimpleWorker` class' `computeLinks` function, which in turn calls `computeLinks` from `linkComputer.ts`. That comment lines up nicely with the description of [`DocumentLinkProvider<T>`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentLinkProvider%3CT%3E)'s `provideDocumentLinks` function, which states:

> Note that the editor ships with a default provider that detects `http(s)` and `file` links.

Fun fact: you can find where it's used in https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode%20computeLinks&type=code, including [`src/vs/workbench/contrib/output/common/outputLinkComputer.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/output/common/outputLinkComputer.ts) and [`src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminalContrib/links/browser/terminalUriLinkDetector.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminalContrib/links/browser/terminalUriLinkDetector.ts).

#### For the builtin link detection in terminal

[The integrated terminal in VS Code has various other capabilities for links](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_links) (including URLs, file links, folder links, and "word links"). The integrated uses [xtermjs](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/), which supports OSC 8 hyperlinks (see also [How to create links in xterm.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64759060/11107541)). VS Code also has several builtin link detector patterns specifically designed to recognize things like file links (that don't use `file://`) in command outputs of popular commandline tools. See [`src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminalContrib/links/browser/terminalLinkParsing.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminalContrib/links/browser/terminalLinkParsing.ts). Also, the word links feature has some extra bits to search following text in a line for info about line numbers and such ([see 1.88 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_additional-context-for-word-links)).

#### For the builtin link detection in Output Panel

The Output Panel also has some special link detection patterns, which you can find in [`src/vs/workbench/contrib/output/common/outputLinkComputer.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/output/common/outputLinkComputer.ts).

#### For extension-contributed link "detection"

As mentioned above, there's the `DocumentLinkProvider` extension API that extension can use to contribute links to documents. If you want to find out how a specific extension is doing that, you'll need to post a question specifically about that extension.

Answer (score -2):

vscode uses ripgrep under the hood. You can find more information about the implementation here https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep

Comment: yes, it does use ripgrep for other features, but not for in-editor link-detection.