# How to write a clickable link in VS Code terminal that points to a multiline range?

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, range, clickable

I want to design a program that can output a clickable path to terminal, but I can't find a way to represent a clickable path with a range.

Is there anyone who knows the answer?

```
Version: 1.87.2 (Universal)
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:21:31.043Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.3.0
```

- When I write `./file:1:2-3:4`, the range is recognized as a position ln 4.
- When I write `./file:1:2:3:4`, it's recognized as a position ln 3 col 4.
- When I write `./file:1-3:2-4`, I'll get a `no matching results` after I click it.

Comment: if it is run by  a task you can add a problem matcher and define what is the file, line and character

Comment: try https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149523

Comment: what do you want to happen with that range, set a selection, what if you want to have a multi selection

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of supported formats in [`terminalLinkParsing`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminalContrib/links/browser/terminalLinkParsing.ts#L9) at the definition of `lineAndColumnRegexClauses`.

At the time of this writing, among the supported formats, I see

- `foo:339:12-789`
- `foo:339:12-341.789`
- `"foo",339.12-789`
- `"foo",339.12-341.789`
- `"foo", lines 339-341`
- `"foo", lines 339-341, characters 12-789`

See also [How does VS Code recognize URLs in text (strings)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77184537/11107541).