VS Code Extension: Working File Link in output panel
In VS Code output panel, writing a URL with http(s):// can be detected as a link. Of course file links (the file_name.ext:line_number:column format) can be detected in terminal. Is it possible to file link to be detected in output panel, too?
Here's an initial code put inside activate() in extension.ts:
    let out = vscode.window.createOutputChannel("sample");
    out.append("./file.txt:3");
    out.show();

Here's a screenshot for output panel with a sample workspace folder. It's not detected as a link.


see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77186228/11107541

From the comment and upon further searching, I found so far that only the absolute path of file in a workspace will be detected as file link in output panel.
Here's my code:
    out.appendLine("file.txt:2");
    out.appendLine("test0\\file.txt:2");
    out.appendLine("\\file.txt:2");
    out.appendLine("\\test0\\file.txt:2");
    out.appendLine(".\\file.txt:2");
    out.appendLine(".\\test0\\file.txt:2");
    out.appendLine("C:\\Users\\gina\\Desktop\\test0\\file.txt:2");
    out.appendLine("C:\\Users\\gina\\Desktop\\file2.txt:3"); // not in workspace

And here's the output:

Only the second to the last was detected as a link.
